# Gmail API: Is message_id unique or is the (thread_id,message_id) tuple unique?

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Through the GMail API, can I assume message_id is unique amongst all the messages I index, or would I have to rely on the (message_id, thread_id) tuple?

Comment: [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) asks for message_id only. So message_id will be unique (in a user inbox or among all emails in gmail is another question :P).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the message_id alone is unique across the inbox (for that single user).

c.f. https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_unique_message_id_x-gm-msgid

Comment: but let's say I have a group that broadcasts the message to 10 client support agent inboxes. What to do if I want to know if at least one of them replied ? Having some unique thread identifier among inboxes would be very helpful ;).

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the reference URL to prove that  "unique across the inbox for that single user". Just now I saw you are "Tech Lead of Gmail APIs at Google" :)

Comment: You don't think this is clear enough from that URL: "Access to the Gmail unique message ID: X-GM-MSGID

Gmail provides a unique message ID for each email so that a unique message may be identified across multiple folders"?